# Sidekiq not running with concurrency greater than 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, sidekiq, sidekiq-monitor

I am testing sidekiq on Rails 3.2 but unless I set concurrency to 1 in sidekiq.yml, jobs are not being processed - Neither locally nor in staging. For example when I set concurrency to 2, on sidekiq dashboard it says busy: 2 but the jobs are never finished.

Any idea where to look?

Comment: What does the job look like? If you strip all the locking you may be doing there and schedule a few of HelloWorld jobs, do _they_ run/finish concurrently?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, thanks: `config.threadsafe!` was not enabled.